# python3 execute wrong file and wrong version

Tags: python

#### Environment

Env: Python 3.11.0rc1
desktop system: win11 , WSL  ubuntu Ubuntu-22.04

#### description

I'm a python newbie, I write a python script named 'deploy.py'  to maintain flow of deployment.
**Recently,  I execute  command in ubuntu with 'python3 deploy.py' ,I get the result of old version of 'deploy.py'**.   It's weird , because in vim or vscode,the content of deploy.sh is the latest version ,if I use vscode to execute deploy.py , It's the right result I want.
**However ,I execute any python script in ubuntu ,I always get the  result is the old version of  deploy.py
**
How can I execute the lastest version of deploy.py
Somebody help , I'll appreciate it.

In WSL  ubuntu command mode , execute the latest version of deploy.py just like vscode.

Comment: Are you sure the file you open in vscode is the same you execute with python? What does `cat deploy.py` show?

Comment: One time, you call your file `deploy.sh` which indicates a shell script. Is this a typo or are you juggling with several files with similar names? Could this be the source of the confusion?

Comment: yes, I'am sure, Daviid,And I confirm the content of deploy.py is lastest in cat

Comment: hi, Friedrich, I confirm ,I don't have deploy.sh , I have only one file named 'deploy.py'

Comment: If cat shows the latest there's no reason `python3 deploy.py` would execute the wrong version. AFAIK it's impossible.

Comment: in other hand, I execute  one python file named 'lock2.py'  ,I get the same result just like  old version of deploy.py. on this occasion , I suspect  if there  are some cache in python system or linux system,

Comment: what happens if you change it to `python3 ./deploy.py`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, could you extract and provide a [mcve] along with precise instructions how to run it? The error is very likely in the parts you don't show, but that's what makes it impossible to tell. Also, it would help if you provided info what you _observed_ and not just your conclusion that it comes from running an obsolete version of your file. Lastly, you can [edit] your question to improve it.